# Google Maps API not loading interface elements properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a website that I'm working on at http://damirsepictrip.com/test-mobile-post/

I'm using the Google Maps API to create a custom map but the Street View icon is not being displayed properly. It's just a vertical bar whereas it needs to be an icon of a person.

Additionally, if you place the icon on the map to use Street View, you will see that as you rotate around, there are parts of the Street View image missing and the close button icon is not showing either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove this:

```
img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

from 
http://damirsepictrip.com/wp-content/themes/starkers/css/base.css

..or try a different selector that doesn't match the images inside the map.

```
img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}

/*override(reset) the setting for images inside the map*/
#location-map img{
  max-width:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought that it was a CSS issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto Dr.Molle's answer above --

The CSS that got this working for me was:

```
.gm-style img{
    max-width:none;
}
```

Unfortunately, setting max-width to none also broke the infowindow close button in Android 2.3.3 for me -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692114/setting-max-width-css-property-to-none-breaks-android-2-3-3-infowindow-close-but

Answer (score 0):

max-height too!

```
#location-map img{ 
    max-width: none !important; 
    max-height: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: Please explain better your answer.