# InfoWindow closing icon not showing in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor

I use this code to create marker and infowindow that shows after clicking on a marker:

```
// latLng and map are created earlier in code
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });

// contentString is just a string with content also created earlier
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

This code produces everything good except one thing, it doesn't show closing icon in upper right corner of info window.

[image]

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

I'm using meteor.js if it makes any difference

This is how I create the `InfoWindow`:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Comment: Your code works for me (the infowindow shows the close icon).  Perhaps a css problem?  You might as an experiment, try the "release version" (specify v=3 in the script include).

Comment: Didn't work. What could it be in css?
I'm live editing css properties in google chrome console but can't find the solution.

Comment: when a feature of the infowindow did not work you better add the code where you create the infowindow

Comment: var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); this is how I create it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API not loading interface elements properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357613/google-maps-api-not-loading-interface-elements-properly)

Comment: http://crib.io.meteor.com/ here is the app, I'm lost. Clicked on marker, found infowindow's html code and played with CSS in Chrome Developer's Console but couldn't get it to work, I found it sometimes work when I set "position: fixed" but it soon breaks. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is the solution for the problem...
It seems google maps have some fun way of dealing with images and there was a problem with css as we thought.
So the solution is just to add this to your css file:

```
img 
{
    max-width: none;
}
```

That's it, enjoy.

Comment: Worked, thanks! I would at least only set the attribute to images on the map like so: `#map_canvas img {max-width: none;}`. Otherwise every image on the website has no max-width (and that maybe breaks responsive design)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. In my case, the infowindow does not show the pointer to the marker. There are some weird looking images in the infowindow as well.

Apparently this has to do with the stylesheet from bootstrap conflicting with google. The following is a much more specific CSS rather than overriding the general CSS

```
/** FIX for Bootstrap and Google Maps Info window styes problem **/
img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"] {
max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution, since this won't affect any of our predefined img rules.

Comment: Worked for me... might want to add the !important flag to make sure - img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"] {max-width:none !important;}

Answer (score 6):

Depending on other css styling you may need to add the !important override...

```
img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"] {
max-width: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, however for those who are looking for answers.  The solution is a CSS override.   Look for in your CSS settings the following css values:

```
.gm-ui-hover-effect{
    top: -27px !important;
    right: -3px !important;
    background: #ddd !important;
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    opacity: 1;}
.gm-ui-hover-effect img{margin: -8px 6px !important;
    width: 16px !important;
    height: 16px !important;}
   .gm-style .gm-style-iw {
    width: 282px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Using these overrides, was able to successfully have the button appear (remove the top and right values) but was also able to format what type of close button I would like to use.   Your CSS values may be different, based on the theme or other plugin installed on your system.  But the .gm_ui_hover-effect and .gm-ui-hover-effect are the key.

A clue to the solution was found here:
https://codepen.io/Marnoto/pen/xboPmG

Combined with using the "inspect" option in Chrome.